# How to prove $f:\mathcal{P}\to (1,2]$ is bijective?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, number-theory

I have difficulty with the following exercise:

> Let  \begin{align*}  
> \mathcal{P}:=\left\{\left\{p_n\right\}_{n=1}^\infty \ \left| \  
> \begin{gathered}
> p_n\in \mathbb{N}  \ \ \text{and}  \ \ p_{n+1}\geq p_n^2 \text{ for any $n\geq 1$;}\\
> p_1\geq 2
> \end{gathered}\right.\right\}
> \end{align*}
> be a space of sequences. For any $\{p_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\in \mathcal{P}$, we define
> \begin{equation} 
> a_n := \prod_{k=1}^n \left(1+ \frac1{p_k}\right), \quad n=1,2,...  \end{equation}
> Show that
>
> 1. For any $\{p_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\in \mathcal{P}$, the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n$ exists; moreover, $1<\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n \leq 2$.
> 2. The map   $ f: \mathcal{P}\to (1,2]$ defined by
>    \begin{align*}  
>     \{p_n\}_{n=1}^\infty &\mapsto  
>    \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n =
>    \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1+ \frac1{p_n}\right) 
>    \end{align*}
>    is a bijection.

Note that $a_n \leq 2\left(1-\frac1{2^n}\right)$. Indeed, $p_n\geq 2^{2^{n-1}}$ for any $n\geq 1$. Suppose $a_{n-1} \leq 2\left(1-\frac1{2^{n-1}}\right)$ is done, then (note that $2^{n-1}\geq n$)
\begin{align*}
a_n &= a_{n-1} \left(1+\frac{1}{p_n}\right) \leq  2\left(1-\frac1{2^{n-1}}\right)\cdot
\left(1+\frac{1}{2^{2^{n-1}}}\right)\\
& \leq  2\left(1-\frac1{2^{n-1}}\right)\cdot
\left(1+\frac{1}{2^{n}}\right) \leq 2\left(1-\frac1{2^n}\right).
\end{align*}
Thus, by induction, we have proved $a_n \leq 2\left(1-\frac1{2^n}\right)<2$ for any $n\geq 1$.
Since the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is strictly increasing and has a upper bound $2$, we deduce that the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n$ exists and $1<\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n \leq 2$ is clear. This proves exercise 1.

If we fix $p_1\geq 2$, take $p_2=p_1^2$, $p_3=p_2^2= p_1^4$,..., $p_n= p_{n-1}^2= p_1^{2^{n-1}}$,..., and then  try to calculate the value of $a_n$, we can find that the result is a geometric series:
\begin{equation}
   a_n = \prod_{k=1}^n  \left(1+ \frac1{p_1^{2^{n-1}}}\right) = \sum_{\ell=0}^{2^{n}-1} \frac{1}{p_1^\ell}=  \frac{p_1}{p_1-1}\cdot \left(1- \frac{1}{p_1^{2^n}}\right). \tag{$\star$}
\end{equation}
(From eq. ($\star$) above, we can also prove exercise 1.)

However, it is just a special case. More generally, I try to expand $a_n$:
\begin{align*}
a_n  = \prod_{k=1}^n \left(1+\frac1{p_k}\right)   = 1+  \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{p_k}+ \sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\frac{1}{p_ip_j} + \sum_{1\leq i<j<k\leq n} \frac{1}{p_ip_jp_k}\cdots+ \frac{1}{p_1p_2\cdots p_n}.
\end{align*}
I don't know what to do next. I guess the bijection $f$ might be related to $2$-adic (or another base?) numbers. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: For convergence in 1. If every $b_n\ge 0$ then $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+b_n)<\infty \iff \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n<\infty$ because (i) $\prod_{n=1}^M(1+b_n)\ge 1+\sum_{n=1}^Mb_n,$ and (ii) $\ln (\prod_{n=1}^M(1+b_n)\,)\le \sum_{n=1}^Mb_n$.... Apply with $b_n=1/p_n.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I see, it's also an effective way for 1. But I don't have any ideas about 2, maybe there are some technical methods I don't know.

Comment: Thoughts about 2. Greedy Algorithm. For $x\in (1,2].$ Let $p(1,x)$ be the least $m\ge 2$ such that $1+1/m<x.$  Let $p(n+1,x)$ be the least $m$ such that $m\ge p(n,x)^2$ and $(1+1/m)\prod_{j\le n}(1+1/p((j,x)\,)<x.$  I think  $\prod_{j\le n}(1+1/p(j,x)\,)$ ought to converge to $x.$